# Ruby on Rails Project Hosted on GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-pages

I'm trying to figure out how to display the home page of my ruby on rails hello world project. It's currently live but I'm getting the README.md file contents instead of the Hello World message, which, is in the application_controller.rb file a few directories in from the root. The README.md file that's showing is at the root. [live project](https://fullstackstaff.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only host a static website with [Github pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

If you want to deploy your rails app I suggest to use the [Heroku free plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6).

Read [this](https://wpamelia.com/static-vs-dynamic-website/) if you want to understand the difference between static and dynamic websites.